# Migrate MoinMoin Wiki to MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, moinmoin

I have a MoinMoin Wiki (version 1.5.7), and i have MediaWiki (version 1.18.2).
I found a few [scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MoinMoin) that can help me import the pages from MoinMoin Wiki to MediaWiki, but the thing is that are not doing the whole proccess.
What is the best approach to import all the pages from MoinMoin Wiki to MediaWiki?
I've never done this before, so i'll really appreciate if you could give me an answer with all the steps.

Answer (score 3):

can't really help with that, but just to explain why the scripts are usually never a complete solution: every wiki owner has that problem only once, so quick hacks that do 80% of the job are rather common.

so the only thing i can advise is to take one of these quickhacks, improve it a bit and contribute the changes upstream.